# Computer Disconnects From Internet - Wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, internet

I don't have a router. My pc has a wireless card. I tried reinstalling the drivers but it keeps happening. Could it be hardware malfunction? Can I buy a new wireless card?

Comment: How do you connect to the Internet?

Comment: Wirelessly? (not sure what you mean) - my pc came with an wireless card, I usually use a free WiFi thingy. Although I know the problem is not from that service since I can connect to that same network with my laptop.

Comment: OK, so you connect to a "cloud" wifi (such as BT OpenZone or "The Cloud")? You may want to change the power settings on the wireless adapter so that the computer doesn't put the device to sleep.

Comment: Oh. There's "Nos" service. Nearby routers with that there's "Nos free internet" which anyone can access if you have an ID and password (my friend gave it to me to use) and so I connect to that. It's for when you're not at home you can access internet if it is a "hotspot" - Anyways, I tried a couple things already (included what you suggested in power settings) right now I can't detail the other one, I'll update soon.